# Strong continuity and $C_0$ semigroups

Tags: semigroup-of-operators

I am trying to understand some properties of semigroups and linear operators for generators of markov processes. My question is about strong continuity and $C_0$ semigroups.

Lets consider a semigroup of linear contractions $(P_t)_{t \geq 0}$. Then I have the definition of strong continuity, when  $\lim_{h \downarrow0}P_h f = f$ 
holds for $f \in X$.

Now my professor introduced also the $C_0$ semigroups with the definition that if for all $f \in C_0(E)$ we have $P_t f \in C_0(E)$ than we call $(P_t)_t$ a $C_0$ semigroup. And we say $f \in C_0(E)$ if it vanishes in infinity and is continuous.

Maybe it is obvious but are both definition equivalent? Because on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup) they say our semigroup is in $C_0$ when the first definition holds.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why do you think that the definitions are equivalent? Why should strong continuity be equivalent to being a $C_0$ semigroup?

Comment: Because my professor used $C_0$ for the second definition but everyone else uses $C_0$ for the first definition. So I thought there is a connection.

Comment: I see... but unfortunately the definitions are not equivalent.

Comment: @saz Most probably the confusion comes from the fact that "$C^0$-semigroup" is a different terminology for a "strongly continuous semigroup" ...

Comment: @Tipumba Of course, this should not be confused with the property that the semigroup is $C_0$-invariant ($C_0$, *not* $C^0$) which is one of the common defining properties ofa *Feller*-semigroup